# Conditional unique constraint in an Informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

Is it possible to create conditional unique constraints in an informix db (my current version is 11.70)

Example of what I would like to do (postgresql):

```
create table test (id int primary key, v varchar(25), a boolean);
create unique index test_index on test(v, a) where a = true;

insert into test values (1, 'l', true);
insert into test values (2, 'k', true);
insert into test values (3, 'l', false);
insert into test values (4, 'l', false);
insert into test values (5, 'l', true); -- Fails because of test_index

select * from test;
-- prints:
-- id   v   a
-- --------------
-- 1    l   true
-- 2    k   true
-- 3    l   false
-- 4    l   false
```

Comment: you should probably make your own check constraint instead of a unique constraint.

Comment: More importantly, I think you want to be able to `INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(5, 'l', false);` which should succeed because `a` is `false`.  Your second `(`l`, true)` insert should fail on both PostgreSQL and Informix because it is violating the uniqueness constraint.  But the short answer is No; there are no such conditional constraints in Informix 11.70.

Comment: You are right @JonathanLeffler I'll update the question. Ugh, so there is no such constraint :( too bad. Any suggestions on other ways to acheive the same result?

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you want `v` to be unique only if `a` is **true**.

Although you can't create a **unique index** you can create a **trigger** over the **DML** operation to achive this.

Example for the **INSERT** operation:

```
[infx1150@tardis ~]$ dbaccess test -

Database selected.

> CREATE TABLE test (
>       id      INT PRIMARY KEY,
>       v       VARCHAR(25),
>       a       BOOLEAN
> );

Table created.

> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(v_val VARCHAR(25), a_val BOOLEAN)
>       DEFINE n INT;
>       LET n = 0;
>
>       IF a_val THEN
>               SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n
>               FROM test
>               WHERE v = v_val
>               AND a = 't';
>
>               IF n > 1 THEN
>                       RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "There is already one row with v = " || v_val || " and a true flag";
>               END IF;
>       END IF;
> END PROCEDURE;

Routine created.

> CREATE TRIGGER ti_test INSERT ON test
>       REFERENCING new AS n
>       FOR EACH ROW (EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_test(n.v, n.a));

Trigger created.

> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'l', 't');

1 row(s) inserted.

> INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'k', 't');

1 row(s) inserted.

> INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 'l', 'f');

1 row(s) inserted.

> INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, 'l', 'f');

1 row(s) inserted.

> INSERT INTO test VALUES (5, 'l', 't');

  746: There is already one row with v = l and a true flag
Error in line 1
Near character position 1
> SELECT * FROM test;


         id v                         a

          1 l                         t
          2 k                         t
          3 l                         f
          4 l                         f

4 row(s) retrieved.

>

Database closed.

[infx1150@tardis ~]$
```

This will work in a database with **transaction logging** (**buffered**, **unbuffered** and **ANSI**) but not on a **non transaction** database.